# Shell Script to Copy file from one server to another

Tags: shell, putty, scp

I have 2 solaris servers. I want to write a shell script which will copy a file from one server to the other.

```
scp /tmp/test/a.war tomcat@202.203.204.44:/tmp/
```

The above command when executed in PUTTY will ask me to enter a password for the destination. This is fine when using PUTTY.

How can iI enter the password while running the `scp` command through shell script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set SSH private/public keys and use -i option during ssh/scp

Comment: Yes, i read about this, is there anyway i can avoid the private\public key bit? Cant use sshpass

Comment: ssh/scp doesn;'t allow interactive sessions. You might need to check how to use "expect" if that can do it. If you have a SAME mount filer available on both machines, then you can just place the file there and it can be accessed from both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup SSH private/public key.

Once generated place the public key line entry on the target server's and user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Make sure the file on the source machine (for the user which will run the scp/ssh command) will have file permission (400) recommended.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182483/scp-without-password-prompt-using-different-username or

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/sshuser-33/index.html or similar online help can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the input file exists
input_file="input.txt"
if [ ! -f "$input_file" ]; then
echo "Error: Input file '$input_file' not found."
exit 1
fi

# Output file to log the copied files and errors
output_file="copied_files.log"

# Read input data line by line from the input file
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
# Extract remote server IP and destination path from the current 
line
remote_server_ip=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
destination_path=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')

# Display what is being read from the input file for 
troubleshooting
echo "Reading from input file:"
echo "REMOTE_SERVER_IP=$remote_server_ip"
echo "DESTINATION_PATH=$destination_path"
echo "-----------------------------"

# Check if remote server IP and destination path are provided
if [ -z "$remote_server_ip" ] || [ -z "$destination_path" ]; then
    echo "Error: Remote server IP or destination path not provided 
in the input file." >> "$output_file"
else
    # List of files to copy
    files_to_copy=("file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3.txt")

    # Copy files to the remote server using scp and log the 
details/errors to the output file
    for file in "${files_to_copy[@]}"; do
        # Check if the file exists in the destination folder
        ssh "$remote_server_ip" "[ -e \"$destination_path/$file\" 
]"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "File: '$file', Server IP: '$remote_server_ip', 
Destination Path: '$destination_path' - Already Exists" >> 
"$output_file"
        else
            # Attempt to copy the file
            scp "$file" "$remote_server_ip":"$destination_path" 2>> 
"$output_file"
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "File: '$file', Server IP: 
'$remote_server_ip', Destination Path: '$destination_path' - Copy 
Successful" >> "$output_file"
            else
                echo "File: '$file', Server IP: 
'$remote_server_ip', Destination Path: '$destination_path' - Copy 
Failed" >> "$output_file"
            fi
        fi
    done
fi
done < "$input_file"

echo "Copying process completed. Details/errors logged in 
'$output_file'."
```